# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.staticfilesbase'

Tags: python, django, modulenotfounderror, django-contrib, django-runserver

Every time I try to run my program using `python manage.py runserver`, this same error comes up:

> "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.staticfilesbase'"

Answer (score 1):

This error typically means that while trying to run your app, either your code or your dependencies is telling django to look for `django.contrib.staticfilesbase` and my best guess is that it is your code.

Start with your `settings.py`. Open it and look under the `installed apps`. It should look at least something like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles', #this is probably where the mistake is
]
```

You can have other app under the "installed apps" ofcourse, but if you find `django.contrib.staticfilesbase` in there, change it to `django.contrib.staticfiles`.

Comment: It is django.contrib.staticfiles, but after removing  my app - 'base.apps.BaseConfig' from installed_apps ,  server ran.

Comment: then template regarding error came, then I added 'base', it's debugged then.